# Slow load_plugin_textdomain and load_default_textdomain

Tags: wordpress, performance, localization

I installed Wordpress on my hosting and it is super slow. (3s page generating). Then I installed Wordpress to localhost and performance is the same. I used xDebug to figure out what is the bottleneck. Almost 60% of time takes `load_plugin_textdomain` and `load_default_textdomain`. I don't know why. Can somebody help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and file is at url: http://data.im-art.cz/cs_CZ.mo, http://data.im-art.cz/cs_CZ.po

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can break that down to time spent within the `import_from_reader` method?

Comment: Also please post your default text domain MO file. That one file seems to be taking more time than everything else put together.

Comment: I added the images and mo file.

Comment: you've posted woocommerce files not the default domain. I was looking at the `load_default_textdomain` call in your first image. That's the one taking the longest by far

Comment: Sorry, I changed urls to domain files

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Extensive costs (using cachegrind's terminology) for load_default_textdomain and load_plugin_textdomain are a somewhat-known and confirmed inefficiency in WordPress. Other profilers do agree on this topic as well, and depending on the exact scenario, they can easily double the overall page load time:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32052

Simplified: on every single page load for non-english installations, WordPress does load and parse translations files into memory, but discards the parsed information after the page has been loaded. This load/parse operation is quite CPU-intensive and does spend quite a significant amount of time.

Those translation files used to be plain-text files (.po), but later moved to compiled binary files (.mo), somehow lessening the overhead. However, even today, it's still around 35-40% in terms of "cost" (using cachegrind's terminology).

There are a few (less-known) plugins around to "fix" this by caching the parsed translations:

- https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/fast-translate/
- https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/mo-cache/
- https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/speed-up-translation/
- https://github.com/inpsyde/translation-cache
- https://www.bjornjohansen.com/wordpress-translations-loading-time

… are just a few examples and closer investigations on that topic.

Those plugins do usually replace the default routine by one which does include caching and often also is more efficient in parsing the un-cached data. The cached information is usually being stored as transient cache data, using WP's Object Cache API. Unless there's special software like Memcached or Redis available and some Object Cache plugin to interface the transient API with those services, WordPress by default does store transient data in its own MySQL database.

As most hosting providers do provide networked MySQL servers, one may accidentally replace a CPU-intensive operation by a network-intensive operation, replacing one kind of cause for a high page load time by a different one. If your WordPress does have access to a local Redis or Memcache instance, you can give the plugins mentioned above a try.

While using PHP's OPcache is generally recommended, it doesn't provide that much benefit: OPcache does compile and cache the PHP source, but executing the cached source to parse the translation files is still about as expensive as without OPcache.

Moving to SSD-based hosting also doesn't improve: the affected files are being loaded for every single page view, so they're very frequently used and likely served from the Kernel's buffer cache without requiring any read operation from any kind of file system or block device.

Caching the "once-executed" PHP output (by using special cache plugins, a CDN or modules like nginx fastcgi cache) does successfully hide any kind of inefficiency somewhere else buried in some other WordPress plugin or WP Core. Depending on the exact solution and deployment, invalidating such cached content may become quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Make sure XDebug is disabled in production and cache the front end of your site.

---

Your profiling results are done with XDebug enabled (as they have to be). Looking at the absolute speeds is misleading, because XDebug is itself the reason they're slow.

On my five year old Macbook Pro I get almost exactly the same results as you. Approximately 1.4 seconds to load the translations from your `cs_CZ.mo` file. If I disable the profiling this drops to 88 milliseconds. (about x16 faster). And if I disable XDebug completely this drops to 30ms (about x47 faster).

So my first question about your slow page loads would be - **is XDebug enabled in production**? If it is, switch it off.

If you don't have XDebug enabled and you still get slow page loads, I think the boring answer is to cache your pages as much as possible. There are many plugins to do this. Personally I have my entire site behind Cloudflare. Traffic barely hits my own server.

Despite the slow profiling speeds, no doubt the bottleneck is still the bottleneck, but that's not hugely surprising as you're loading several thousand translations on every page view. Even at a few tens of milliseconds each, it can add up.

You can't rewrite the WordPress functions. They take as long as they take. But perhaps you can improve disk I/O. Drilling into the `MO::import_from_reader` method, it looks like about 40% of the time is spent outside of PHP code (i.e. probably reading the open files). A hosting provider that offers SSDs might give you a boost, but I'm reaching. I think caching is the best route.